# Mongo DB Atlas Snaphots are lost

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm run to a stange issue in mongo db atlas restores.
Whenever I restore a snapshort via mongo db atlas UI  , this snapshorts moves from the "SnapShots" to the "Restore History" tan.
From this minue , there is no option to use this snapshort anymore as its gone from the UI and lost forever.

This is where I click the restore :
 [image]

After a succusfull restore , I see the restore History , but there i sno way to restore using that snapshot again

[image]

Am I missing something ?
How do I use a snapshot which I have used before ?

Thanks
Sagi

Comment: Which snapshot did you restore? Before & after screen captures will be helpful.